# How to add to scala.collection.mutable.Buffer

Tags: scala, mutable

In scala, I would like to accumulate the content of a Seq in a Buffer and avoid constructing a new Buffer on every addition. I worked out something like this:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.Buffer
var sum = Buffer[Double](1.0,2.0)
sum.append(3.0)
val add = Seq[Double](4.0,5.0,6.0)
for( i <- 0 until sum.size ) sum.update(i,sum(i)+add(i))
```

Is there a way to avoid the for loop. Anything that I've tried with zip ends with a reassignment to val error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zip` doesn't help much if you want to avoid creating a new `Buffer`, but you could use `zipWithIndex` to figure out the index to which you should add the current element, and `view` to avoid creating sequences in memory:

```
add.view.zipWithIndex.foreach {
  case (value, index) => sum(index) += value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sum = add.zip(sum).map(item => item._1+item._2).toBuffer
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. Is this efficient, though? Doesn't this line create  a new Buffer in memory that is then assigned to sum? Thinking in terms of c++ it would create a lot of memory overhead?